# Javascript Copy function handle not working

Tags: javascript

I am writing copy button for code-blocks, but the button can not handle "copy" event.

The buttons are created with `createElement` method, and event added to the buttons with `addEventListener` to the buttons, before appending to the blocks, through `foreach` loop.

**[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dsmith33/5jzbs94c/6/)** of the blocks

Create Button code:

```
const textspan = document.createElement("SPAN");
const bgbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");

bgbutton.classList.add("btnCopy", "badge");
bgbutton.innerText = "copy";
bgbutton.addEventListener('click', copytextHandle);

textspan.appendChild(bgbutton);

const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre");

codeSyn.forEach(function(el) {
    el.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', textspan);
})
```

In my text, I have three blocks, but only one button is visible(last), first two blocks has no button.

Also, the click event, and functionality can not implemented with `click` hook. The problem is straight about, click event, please mention which causing the error.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace(/^\r?\n/, "");
    }
    
    const textspan = document.createElement("SPAN");
    const bgbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    
    bgbutton.classList.add("btnCopy", "badge");
    bgbutton.innerText = "copy";
    bgbutton.addEventListener('click', copytextHandle);

    textspan.appendChild(bgbutton);
    
    const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
    
    codeSyn.forEach(function(el) {
        el.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', textspan);
    })  
})

const copytextHandle = (e) => {
    const codeBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".hljs-ln")[e.target.dataset.idx];
    const text = codeBlock
       .innerText
       .trim()
       .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
       .replace(/}/g, "}\n")
          .replace(/{ /g, "{\n  ")
          .replace(/;/g, ";\n  ")
        copySuccess.classList.remove('hide');
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => setTimeout(() => bgbutton.innerHTML("Copied"),200),
      (e) => {
        console.log('Error writing to the clipboard', e.message);
         copySuccess.classList.add('hide');
       }
    );  
};
```

```css
span > button.btnCopy {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
}

pre {
  position: relative;
}

.btnCopy{border:none; background-color: #e8e8e8;}
/*background-color:a5a5a5, 9c9c9c*/
.btnCopy:hover{background-color: #585858}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS Multiple blocks</h3>
    <h4>First Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Second Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Third Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're only getting the button on the last code block because you only created one button. In your loop you add it to the first code block, then you **move** it to the 2nd block, then you move it to the last. You need to [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the button to add it to each block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking the button `copy` you can get to a `<table>` element which is inside one of your `<code>` elements with this code:

```
const codeBlock = e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.children[0];
```

Once that is applied, the text within `<code>` gets copied to the variable `text` which we can see by running the code below and checking the console output.

The `copy` buttons now appear on all `<code>` blocks. I've added the code to create the `button` and `span` inside the `codeSyn.forEach(function(el) { ... }`, so that new elements are created for every `<pre>` that you are iterating through.

Another problem that arises is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: copySuccess is not defined

To resolve this error you should assign an HTML element that has class `hide` to the variable `copySuccess` so that this works:

```
copySuccess.classList.remove('hide');
```

---

**Check the below code:**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var copySuccess = document.getElementById("copySuccess");
    var y = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace(/^\r?\n/, "");
    }
    
    const codeSyn = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
    
    codeSyn.forEach(function(el) {
        const textspan = document.createElement("SPAN");
        const bgbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    
        bgbutton.classList.add("btnCopy", "badge");
        bgbutton.innerText = "copy";
        bgbutton.addEventListener('click', copytextHandle);

        textspan.appendChild(bgbutton);
        el.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', textspan);
    })  
})

const copytextHandle = (e) => {
    const codeBlock = e.target.parentNode.nextSibling.children[0];
    const text = codeBlock
       .innerText
       .trim()
       .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
       .replace(/}/g, "}\n")
          .replace(/{ /g, "{\n  ")
          .replace(/;/g, ";\n  ");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => setTimeout(() => e.target.innerHTML = "copied",2000),
      (e) => {
        console.log('Error writing to the clipboard', e.message);
      }
    );
};
```

```css
span > button.btnCopy {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
}

pre {
  position: relative;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btnCopy{border:none; background-color: #e8e8e8;}
/*background-color:a5a5a5, 9c9c9c*/
.btnCopy:hover{background-color: #585858}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS Multiple blocks <span id="copySuccess" class="hide">Copied...</span></h3>
    <h4>First Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Second Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <h4>Third Code block</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BrownPaul edited the answer above to have the button -> copied

Comment: did you checked this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67043033/react-block-showing-unnecessary-br-tag

Answer (score 0):

What is happeninig is you're moving the same button in a loop all the way to last pre. Use eg. [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to make a new button per pre element.

simple move scenario (https://jsfiddle.net/jtg6fczd/)

```
document.querySelector("div").append(button) // adds button to div
document.body.append(button) // moves button out of div
```

Comment: see the copy button location: https://snipboard.io/DVO30h.jpg

Comment: forgot to revert there: https://jsfiddle.net/89gnrLx4/29/