# React block showing unnecessary br tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building snippet block to add code inside `<pre><code>` tag.

However, when the code viewed - the `<pre>` tag is having unnecessary tag.

My snippet block react code

```
  edit({ attributes, setAttributes, isSelected }) {
    const { text } = attributes;

    return (
      <Fragment>        
            <RichText
              identifier="text"
              value={text}
              placeholder={__('Text')}
              onChange={nextText => {
                setAttributes({
                  text: nextText,
                });
              }}
            />
      </Fragment>
    );
  },

  save({ attributes }) {
    const { text } = attributes;

    return (
      <pre>
          {text && (<code>{text}</code> )}
      </pre>
    );
  },
};
```

The code inserted from gutenberg editor - for testing.

```
Python program to illustrate destructor
class Employee:
Initializing
def __init__(self):
print('Employee created.')
Deleting (Calling destructor)
def __del__(self): print('Destructor called, Employee deleted.')
obj = Employee()
del obj
```

But the above test snippet is pulled as:
[image: snippet]
the rendered snippet block without line break and 
 tag.

**The issue originated** from HTML storing. the issue coming from wrong formatting during storing.

the stored snippet in mysql.
[image: stored-snippet]

How to resolve this. So that the code can be stored and viewed inside the `<pre><code>` block with line break, without unnecessary class in `<pre>` tag

Comment: The following links from the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) and from [WP stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/369453/block-validation-fails-in-html-content-escaped-by-save-function) will surely help you. I suggest reading them CAREFULLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React will by default escape your HTML to prevent cross site scripting attacks (XSS) to your website. If you want to post plain HTML you should use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop on your HTML element and pass the `innerHTML` as an object where the key is `__html` and the value is the HTML you would like to post.

> ### dangerouslySetInnerHTML
>
> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, **you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous**.

So you would write your code as:

```
<pre>
    {text && ( <code dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text}} /> )}
</pre>
```

---

In regards to the `wp-block-example-snippet` class that gets automatically added to your `<pre>` element, you can remove it by adding this to your theme's function.php file in wordpress:

```
function wpassist_remove_block_library_css(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpassist_remove_block_library_css' );
```

Although note that this will remove the Gutenberg's automatically added CSS file from your website:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='https://nextseasontv.com/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Gutenberg uses these CSS libraries to manage blocks on your site’s frontend. If you are not using them you can remove them by the above instruction.